# Using Highcharts library in swing application

Tags: java, swing, highcharts

Is there any way to use the Highcharts library in swing application? I know there is a GWT wrapper for them, but did not find any solution for Swing. Interested in this very library or its wrappers.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just use a pattern for and html page with highchart usage (can be stored in the file), put my data there, then useing JavaFx show it. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts, don't think so.  But there any [several charting choices](http://www.fromdev.com/2012/09/Free-Open-Source-Java-Charting-Library.html) for Swing and for [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/jfxpub-charts.htm)